# File manager's "Open with..." menu duplicates entries

Tags: filemanager, 22.10

Ubuntu 22.10.
Would you please help me to figure out why these entries were duplicated and how do I remove them.
Thanks you in advance.

[image]

Comment: At this point in time I would suggest a bug report is the way to go. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: You could see if there is anything wrong in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. You could even make some changes there (make a backup first).

Comment: Thanks, but edting of ~/.config/mimeapps.list does not help. The problem still exists.